# Sentry with loggingIntegration in python not observing event_level=logging.CRITICAL

Tags: python, exception, logging, sentry

I have a python script that initialises sentry like so:

```
def sentry_init():
    sentry_sdk.init(
        'some dsn',
        traces_sample_rate=1.0,
        environment='staging',
        integrations=[
            LoggingIntegration(
                level=logging.INFO,  # Capture info and above as breadcrumbs
                event_level=logging.CRITICAL,  # Send records as events
            ),
        ],
    )

def foo():
    # calls functions from another script which also logs

if __name__ == "__main__":
   
    sentry_init()
    logging.basicConfig(level='INFO')
    log = logging.getLogger('foo')
    log.addHandler(HttpApiHandler())
    foo()
```

in another module called `modb` which has functions called from `foo()` I also have logging setup with `log = logging.getLogger(__name__)`

```
# modb
import logging
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def modfunc():
    try:
        if:
            # Some conditions
        else:
            raise Exception("Some error")
    except Exception as e:
         log.error(str(e))
```

so `modb` has a catchall which is handled by logging an `ERROR`. But I am seeing this `ERROR` logged in sentry. How is this possible if I initialised sentry to only log `CRITICAL` or above ?

This problem is not occuring when an `ERROR` is thrown **from within the main module** its only happening from sub modules called from the main one.